# Google anlytics - Custom dimensions not work for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, unity-game-engine

I've upgraded Google Analytics Unity SDK from version 3 to 4. All of tracking events & screens are showing up but custom dimensions only works for iOS. While custom dimensions are working just fine for both Android and iOS in SDK version 3.

First, I declare public GoogleAnalytics variable and assign configurations:

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsAdaptor : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GoogleAnalyticsV4 ga;

    void Start()
    {
        ga = UnityRoot.Instance.gameObject.AddComponent<GoogleAnalyticsV4>();

        ga.IOSTrackingCode = config.IOSTrackingCode;
        ga.androidTrackingCode = config.androidTrackingCode;
        ga.otherTrackingCode = config.otherTrackingCode;
        ga.productName = config.productName;
        ga.bundleIdentifier = config.bundleIdentifier;
        ga.bundleVersion = config.bundleVersion;
        ga.sendLaunchEvent = config.sendLaunchEvent;
        ga.UncaughtExceptionReporting = config.reportUncaughtException;
        ga.dispatchPeriod = 2;
    }
```

Then a method is call by other class to fire Google Analytics event:

```
public void RecordEvent(AnalyticsEvent e)
{
    var s = new EventHitBuilder();

    // category + action + label + value       
    s.SetEventCategory(e.Category);
    s.SetEventAction(e.Action);

    if(e.Label != null)
        s.SetEventLabel(e.Label);

    if(e.Campaign != null)
        s.SetCampaignName(e.Campaign);

    if (e.Value is int || e.Value is long)
        s.SetEventValue((long)e.Value);

    InfoDataCollection<EventHitBuilder>(s);

    int dimensionIndex;

    if (customDimensionIndexLookup.TryGetValue(dimension.Key, out dimensionIndex))
    {
        s.SetCustomDimension(dimensionIndex, dimension.Value);
    }

    ga.LogEvent(s);
}
```

The same also applied to screen:

```
public void RecordScreen(AnalyticsScreen screen)
{        
    var appViewBuilder = new AppViewHitBuilder();

    appViewBuilder.SetScreenName(screen.Name);
    if (screen.Campaign != null)
        appViewBuilder.SetCampaignName(screen.Campaign);

    InfoDataCollection<AppViewHitBuilder>(appViewBuilder);

    int dimensionIndex;

    if (customDimensionIndexLookup.TryGetValue(dimension.Key, out dimensionIndex))
    {
        appViewBuilder.SetCustomDimension(dimensionIndex, dimension.Value);
    }         

    ga.LogScreen(appViewBuilder);
}
```

customDimensionIndexLookup.TryGetValue will return custom dimensions index according to the string, for example `UserId`. InfoDataCollection adds addition custom dimension to all event & screen:

```
private void InfoDataCollection<T>(T hitBuilder) where T : HitBuilder<T>
{
    int dimensionIndex;
    if (customDimensionIndexLookup.TryGetValue("UserId", out dimensionIndex) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccountPortal.CurrentAccountID))
    {
        hitBuilder.SetCustomDimension(dimensionIndex, AccountPortal.CurrentAccountID);
    }
}
```

Event and screen data are appearing in report except when I applied custom dimension to it with data segment of `Android traffic` and `iOS traffic` there are only data for iOS while Android traffic show 0 record.

And Both Android & iOS are using the same code.

What is the cause of this missing data? Any idea or advise is appreciated. Last resort I had in mind is to fallback to version 3, which was already deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. It seems that Google Analytics SDK for Unity lack implementation in GoogleAnalyticsAndroidV4.cs methods.

To track custom dimension in event you have to modify the code to:

```
internal void LogEvent(EventHitBuilder builder) 
{
    AndroidJavaObject eventBuilder = new AndroidJavaObject("com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders$EventBuilder");
    eventBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setCategory", new object[] { builder.GetEventCategory() });
    eventBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", new object[] { builder.GetEventAction() });
    eventBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setLabel", new object[] { builder.GetEventLabel() });
    eventBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setValue", new object[] { builder.GetEventValue() });

    foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> i in builder.GetCustomDimensions())
    {
        eventBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setCustomDimension", new object[] { i.Key, i.Value });
    }

    foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> i in builder.GetCustomMetrics())
    {
        eventBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setCustomMetric", new object[] { i.Key, i.Value });
    }   

    object[] builtEvent = new object[] { eventBuilder.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("build") };
    tracker.Call("send", builtEvent);
}
```

The same also apply to screen as well.

Comment: If you are using the latest analytics from android sdk (eg. 9.2.1), when calling setCustomMetric, you need to convert the second parameter to float first. Otherwise, you will get MethodNotFound error